# Coefficients of this generating function

Tags: combinatorics, discrete-mathematics, generating-functions

For the first part of a problem, I solved the generating function to be $F(x) = \frac{x^3}{(1-x)^2}$

Now it's the easy part that has me a little confused. What would the coefficients be in this case?

I have computed so far:

$$\frac{x^3}{(1-x)^2} = x^3 (1+2x+3x^2 + \dots) =x^3 + 2x^4 + 3x^5 + \dots$$

Which leads me to believe that $f(n)=(n-2)$. But I know this only holds true for $ \ge 2$. What am i missing?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is the binomial theorem, which says that 
$$(1+x)^n = \sum_{k \ge 0} \binom{n}{k} x^k$$

This is true even when $n$ is not necessarily a positive integer; we just have to define the binomial coefficient properly: for nonnegative integer $k$ and any $n$, we define
$$\binom{n}{k} = \frac{n(n-1)\cdots(n-k+1)}{k!}$$

With that definition, we have 
$$\binom{-2}{k} = \frac{(-2)(-3)\cdots(-2-k+1)}{k!} = (-1)^k \frac{2\cdot 3 \cdots (k+1)}{k!} = (-1)^k (k+1).$$

Thus, 
$$\frac{x^3}{(1-x)^2} = x^3(1-x)^{-2} = x^3\sum_{k \ge 0} \binom{-2}{k} x^k = x^3\sum_{k \ge 0} (k+1) x^k = \sum_{k \ge 0} (k+1) x^{k+3}$$

As the exponent is $k+3$, we can make the substitution $m = k+3$ (and so $k +1 = m - 2$) to get the above to be equal to
$$\sum_{k \ge 0} (k+1)x^{k+3} = \sum_{m \ge 3} (m-2) x^m$$

This means that the coefficient of any $x^m$ is 
$$[x^m]\frac{x^3}{(1-x)^2} = \begin{cases}
(m-2) & \text{if $m \ge 3$} \\
0 & \text{otherwise}
\end{cases}$$

Comment: Ok, thanks a lot. I was confused because I wasn't sure if it was ok to represent it as a piece wise function. Doesn't your equation hold for all m>=2?

Comment: @User38: It happens to, but it's only a coincidence that the expression $(m-2)$ takes the value $0$ at $m=2$. In general multiplying a power series by $x^3$ would mean that all coefficients $x^2$ and below are zero. (For example, $x^3/(1-x)$ has coefficient of $x^m$ being $1$ for all $m \ge 3$; in that case the formula doesn't extend to $m = 2$.)

Answer (score 1):

We expand $(\frac{1}{1-x})^{2} = \sum_{i=0}^{\infty} \binom{i + 2 - 1}{i} x^{i}$. And then multiply the expansion by $x^{3}$.

Comment: It's the multiplying by x^(3) which is confusing me. What does that do to the coefficients?

Comment: It just shifts the exponents by three. So if $k$ is the coefficient of $x^{i}$ under $(\frac{1}{1-x})^{2}$, then multiplying by $x^{3}$ says that $k$ is the coefficient of $x^{i+3}$.

Comment: @ ml0105 I realize that, but how then do I define the coefficients of x^(i)? We know the coefficients on x^(i+3) are (i+1), but what about x^(i)? My expansion suggests that f(i)=(i-2) for i>=2, and 0 for i=0 and 1. Is this the only way to define it?